# Using Redux how do you stop the switch in the reducer growing?

Tags: angular, redux, angular5, flux, ng2-redux

Using Redux how do you stop the switch in the reducer growing?

**I'm using angular 5 and ng2-Redux.**

I'm using the reducer and a switch but I'm worried that the switch will grow as I add more action types.

Currently I'm trying to use a red combine reducer to manage the growth of the state and the files:

**I currently get this error:**

> Unhandled Promise rejection: Reducer "app" returned undefined during
>   initialization. If the state passed to the reducer is undefined, you
>   must explicitly return the initial state. The initial state may not be
>   undefined. If you don't want to set a value for this reducer, you can
>   use null instead of undefined. ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ;
>   Value: Error: Reducer "app" returned undefined during initialization.
>   If the state passed to the reducer is undefined, you must explicitly
>   return the initial state. The initial state may not be undefined. If
>   you don't want to set a value for this reducer, you can use null
>   instead of undefined.

Seems like the rootReducer needs to return state but I'm using a combine reducer.

**My Reducer Service code:**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

export interface IAppState {
    counter?: number;
    user?: Object;
    numberOfMessages?: number;
}

export interface IAction {
    type: string;
    payload?: any;
}

export const INITIAL_APP_STATE: IAppState = {
    counter: 0,
    user: {},
    numberOfMessages: 0
};

export const appReducer = (state: IAppState, action: IAction): IAppState => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'INCREMENT':
        return  {
            counter: state.counter + action.payload,
            numberOfMessages: state.numberOfMessages
        };
    }
    return state;
};

export const userReducer = (state: IAppState, action: IAction): IAppState => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'DECREMENT':
        return  {
            counter: state.counter,
            numberOfMessages: state.numberOfMessages - action.payload
        };
    }
    return state;
};

export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  app: appReducer,
  user: userReducer
});
```

**This is my module export section for the redux setup (ERROR HERE I THINK????):**

```
export class AppModule {
  constructor(ngRedux: NgRedux<IAppState>) {
    ngRedux.configureStore(rootReducer, INITIAL_APP_STATE);
  }
}
```

**This is my dispatch method:**

```
 public increment(): void {
    this.ngRedux.dispatch({
      type: '[app] INCREMENT',
      payload: 1
    });
  }

 public decrement(): void {
    this.ngRedux.dispatch({
      type: '[user] DECREMENT',
      payload: 2
    });
  }
```

Comment: you can find a answer in the other question that you made about this subject.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48950721/in-angular-v5-how-do-i-listen-to-my-apps-redux-state-object-changing/48980172#48980172

Comment: @Ricardo im currently having trouble wiring up the rootReducer to the configuration in app module, which is a combineReducer. See above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should split up your `IAppState` into different feature states:

```js
export interface IAppState = {
  auth: IAuthState;
  onboarding: IOnboardingState;
  feedback: IFeedbackState;
};
```

Then you build up your `rootReducer` from all the feature reducers using `combineReducers` from `'redux'`:

```js
export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  auth: authReducer,
  onboarding: onboardingReducer,
  feedback: feedbackReducer
});
```

Your feature states, actions, reducers and epics will therefore be smaller and easier to maintain.

You can add feature specific prefixes to your action names to ensure they are unique:

```js
export class CounterActions {
  static INCREMENT: string = '[COUNTER] INCREMENT';
  static DECREMENT: string = '[COUNTER] DECREMENT';
  static RANDOMIZE: string = '[COUNTER] RANDOMIZE';
```

### UPDATE: Your follow-up problem

The solution is in the error message, read carefully:

> If the state passed to the reducer is undefined, you must explicitly
>   return the initial state.

You need to pass in the initial state as a default value:

```js
export const userReducer = (state: IUserState = INITIAL_USER_STATE, action: IAction): IAppState => {
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'LOGIN':
        return  {
            userName: action.payload.userName
        };
    }
    return state;
};
```

Also, the `userReducer` only gets the `IUserState` slice of the state passed in.

Comment: how does it now which of those three reducers to use?

Comment: Your action names need to be unique, since they will still pass through all reducers. You can achieve that by adding a feature specific prefix to all your actions.

Comment: Depending on your use case, fractal stores might be an option for you. Have a look at https://github.com/angular-redux/store/blob/master/articles/fractal-store.md

Comment: can you show me an example above of the prefix for an action so that a specific reducer will be called

Comment: I have already edited my answer ;-) The correct feature reducer will update your store because of your actions' uniqueness.

Comment: I've updated my attempt using the combine reducer above. But getting an error. Can you edit my attempt. I think its the combineReducer setup breaking in the app module setup part

Comment: can you take a look at this related redux question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49008341/using-redux-in-angular-5-how-do-i-get-the-browser-to-remember-the-previous-save