# Using Redux in angular 5 how do I get the browser to remember the previous save state on refresh

Tags: angular, redux, react-redux, ng2-redux

Currently, on refresh, I loose the saved state.

I'm not sure if I need to do anything in the **app module**.

I'm using angular5, typescript, webpack with **ng2-Redux and Redux**.

**This is my current app module class:**

```
export class AppModule {
  constructor(ngRedux: NgRedux<IAppState>) {
    ngRedux.configureStore(rootReducer, INITIAL_APP_STATE, [ createLogger() ]);
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if I need to getState on load of the app.
Currently the default INITIAL_APP_STATE is always set thus loosing the stores state in the browsers memory.

Answer (score 4):

It's the normal behavior of the redux, you can try to save your state to a cookie or localstorage and load it on initialisation.

To save state to local storage after each update, you need to create a global reducer that saves the state. (it can cost a lots of CPU if you have a big state)

Comment: I have added middleware so I can use that to update the local storages with the state. But then I might as well use local storages instead of redux?

Comment: I suggest to sync your store to local storage.
This module looks promising : https://github.com/btroncone/ngrx-store-localstorage